# xlwrite changing font format in Excel

Tags: matlab, format, xlsx, excel-2011

I am currently running MATLAB R2013a on OSX and am attempting to write the contents of a cell array into a specified cell of an .xlsx file in Excel 2011 for Mac. When I first tried using the built-in MATLAB function `xlswrite`, I was unsuccessful, and after doing a bit of digging, I came to the conclusion that this function would not work as I needed because `actxserver` is not supported on my Mac. Therefore, I did a bit of research online and found the `xlwrite` function [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38591-xlwrite--generate-xls-x--files-without-excel-on-mac-linux-win).

After downloading the package, I am successfully able to use this code to write the contents of a cell array into a specified cell of my .xlsx file, however, I've run into a problem. How do I get the contents of the cell I am editing to keep the previous .xlsx formatting of the cell? For example, the blank cell I am writing into is set to bold Cambria font size 10, but when I run this code, the contents of the cell change to non-bold Calibri (Body) font size 12. I've tried changing the Excel default font setting, but it always reverts to Calibri (Body) font size 12. Is there a trick to keep the formatting the same? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Commenting from a MATLAB perspective: it's probably better to ask the author of that code whether that's possible from MATLAB. You can go through the code and see whether there's a font specifier somewhere and if that's not the case I think it's solely Excel

Comment: I contacted the author but haven't heard back yet. I went through the xlwrite code but couldn't find anything in regards to formatting, though there are some java functions built into the package that I can't access/don't really understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by Excel behavior. I think that the Style "Normal" (or whatever style your data is in) in Excel has automatically formatted new data with font Calibri.. I personally think it is no big deal.

However if you want to fix, you can try open the Excel file. Select a cell with font Calibri, go to tab **Home** (Excel 2010), then **Cell Styles**, right click **Normal** (or the current style name), then **Modify**. Then untick the box **Font** -> ok. And then Save the file and re-run the Matlab script.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to use a variation of this solution -- instead of unchecking the Font box, I checked it, hit the Format... button, and changed the formatting to how I wanted it to be imported